# Jquery Ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp, bing

For several days we're banging our head to find out the solution but we're not able to figure out why this code is not working.

```
var bing_url='http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?JsonType=callback&JsonCallback=?&Appid=[OurApp Id]&query='+keyword+'&sources=web';

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: bing_url,
  dataType:"jsonp",
  success: function(response)
  {
    $("#result").html('');
    if(response.SearchResponse.Web.Results.length)
    {
      $.each(response.SearchResponse.Web.Results, function(i,data)
      {
        var title=data.Title;
        var dis=data.Description; 
        var url=data.Url;

        var finall="<div class='webresult'><div class='title'><a href='"+url+"'>"+title+"</a></div><div class='desc'>"+dis+"</div><div class='url'>"+url+"</div></div>";
        $("#result").append(final); // Result

      });

      parentwin.document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0).innerHTML += final;
    }
    else
    {
      $("#result").html("<div id='no'>No Results</div>");
    }
  }             //success
});
```

This script will be called from any other web page from IE. It will search results from bing using bing api and then the results will be appended to the original page.

**Problem:**

This script is working when we directly open it. But it does not work when it is called from another page.

Comment: Is there only a problem in IE? If you look in your developer console do you see any requests going out?

Comment: Also, do some debugging. If you replace the success callback with function(){ alert(1) }, does it work? Find out the exact point at which it fails.

Comment: @nicholaides success callback is not showing alert when we run it from other web page otherwise it is working and showing the results from bing search api.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are violating [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You can access only files which are located on same server as the script.

Also from wiki article about [XmlHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) object:

> XMLHttpRequest is subject to the browser's same origin policy in that, for security reasons, requests will only succeed if they are made to the same server that served the original web page. There are alternative ways to circumvent this policy if required.

Comment: @tresko thanks for the response.But **when we are directly running the script it runs fine** but when it is called from another webpage it is not working if its violation of same origin policy then how it is working when it is executed directly.

Comment: @user1254630 : *This script is working when we directly open it. But it does not work when it is called from another page.* .. this is what you wrote.